# simple rounded borders with JQUERY or something else

Tags: css, rounded-corners

**Duplicate:**

- [What is the best way to create rounded corners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7089/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-rounded-corners-using-css)
- [How to make a cross browser, W3C valid, semantic, non-javascript ROUND corner?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/746627/)
- [jQuery rounded corners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270380/jquery-round-corners)

Do you know a way to make rounded borders to div elements.
I used ruzee but i got problem to use CalenderExtender(asp.net ajax) and GMDatePicker components.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In CSS 3 there will be a standard for that. Today you can do it (only for Mozilla and Webkit based browsers) with:

```
.roundBorder {
    -moz-border-radius: 1em;
    -webkit-border-radius: 1em;
}
```

Otherwise you can use multiple divs with backgound-images, but JQuery will provide a more simple way (that I don't know about :()

The multiple div way could look something like this:

html:

```
<div class="topLeft">
    <div class="topRight">
        <div class="bottomLeft">
            <div class="bottomRight">
                 <div class="content">
                 </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.topLeft {
    background-image: url('topLeft.png');
    background-position: top left;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.topRight {
    background-image: url('topRight.png');
    background-position: top right;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.bottomLeft {
    background-image: url('bottomLeft.png');
    background-position: bottom left;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.bottomRight {
    background-image: url('bottomRight.png');
    background-position: bottom right;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: What does your question refer to? If you asked about [...]-border-radius: Since this is only working with mozilla or webkit it wont work for IE (neither for opera). If you asked about the second part (the stacked divs): this should work in every common browser.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the CSS3 border-radius property, but this isn't supported in IE yet.

Comment: Great news. Would you add new another features of CSS3?

Answer (score 1):

for JQuery, you could use 'Corner'. See [here](http://malsup.com/jquery/corner/)

Comment: I don't know why but i couldn't register it(even if i add js file to the page)